# How to get/call the path for a .wav in a resource file

Tags: java, audio, resources

OK so I have a .wav in a resource file I made called sound. The path for the file name I want is /music/sound/One.wav . I tried to replace this with the path I had for the old path I had when i didn't have it in the resource file. I want to do it this way so i can make a jar file and have people play it. The code part I have is:

```
public class AL implements ActionListener {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    InputStream in;

    try {

        String wav = "C:\\Users\\Mike\\workspace\\music\\sound\\One.wav";
        in = new FileInputStream(wav);
        AudioStream audio = new AudioStream(in);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audio);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }}}
```

I have been reading around and way something about get class and resource but had no luck. Help would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
try (InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("sound/One.wav")) {
    if (in != null) {
        AudioStream audio = new AudioStream(in);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audio);
    }
}
```

or maybe just `"One.wav"`, depending on how you set up your classpath. Since this is in Eclipse, you probably want `sound` to be a source directory. When you migrate this to a jar, make sure it either contains `sound/One.wav` or `One.wav` in that path.

Comment: Like below I posted the code I changed it to. I know the file location is right because i did sound/One.wav before I changed it to how you had it. When I try it with whats posted nothing happens after I click the start. I seem to get a null pointer exception.